# Why componentDidMount makes app to collapse?

Tags: reactjs

I'm learning React and I'm trying to use componentDidmount.
But for some reason this method crash all the application.

I am using visual studio code and it paints the all componentDidMount in red.
The error I get is:

> `Line 11:  Typo in component lifecycle method declaration  react/no-typos`

Comment: Please, include add your code to the question.

Comment: This might be your issue: https://github.com/facebook/prop-types/issues/264 But yeah, code might help.

Comment: should be "componentDidMount", I guess, it's because of that M letter.

Comment: Your lint is clearly pointing you the error. There is a typo in the lifecycle method in line 11 of your code. These messages are your allies, read them, they can be very informative.

Comment: Thank you everyone, the problem is solved.